# How to close opened transaction in rx-java and rxjava-jdbc to avoid TransactionAlreadyOpenException

Tags: rx-java

**DbUtils.java**

```
public final class DbUtils {

    private final static Database DATABASE = Database.from("jdbc:h2:mem:" + App.DB_NAME + ";INIT=runscript from '~/create.sql';MODE=ORACLE");

    public static Database database() {
        synchronized (Lock.class) {
            return DATABASE;
        }
    }

}
```

**PersonService.java**

```
public class PersonService {

    private final Database db;

    public PersonService(Database db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public Observable<Integer> insert(Person person) {
        Observable<Boolean> beginTransaction = db.beginTransaction();
        Observable<Integer> count = db.update("insert into person values (?, ?, ?, ?)")
                .dependsOn(beginTransaction)
                .parameters(person.getId(), person.getName(), person.getAddress(), person.getContact())
                .count();
        db.commit(count);
        return count;
    }

    //.......

}
```

**PersonServiceTest.java**

```
public class PersonServiceTest {

    final PersonService personService = new PersonService(DbUtils.database());

    public PersonServiceTest() {
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("@Person#insert()")
    public void testInsert() {
        Observable<Integer> insert1 = personService.insert(new PersonBuilder()
                .setId(1).setName("Bhuwan")
                .setAddress("KTM")
                .setContactNo("22222").createPerson()
        );
        insert1.subscribe((Integer count) -> {
            Person person = personService.find(1);
            System.out.println(person.toString());
            assertNotNull(person);
            assertEquals("Bhuwan", person.getName());
        });

        Observable<Integer> insert2 = personService.insert(new PersonBuilder()
                .setId(1).setName("BhuwanUpadhyay")
                .setAddress("Dhangadhi")
                .setContactNo("111111").createPerson()
        );

        insert2.subscribe((Integer count) -> {
            Person person = personService.find(1);
            System.out.println(person.toString());
            assertNotNull(person);
            assertEquals("BhuwanUpadhyay", person.getName());
        });
    }

}
```

---

I got following exception but i don't understand how to close opened transaction in [rxjava-jdbc](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-jdbc) library. Please, anybody know how to close opened transaction on this library.

```
Caused by: com.github.davidmoten.rx.jdbc.exceptions.TransactionAlreadyOpenException
    at com.github.davidmoten.rx.jdbc.Database.beginTransactionObserve(Database.java:647)
    at com.github.davidmoten.rx.jdbc.QueryContext.beginTransactionObserve(QueryContext.java:45)
    at com.github.davidmoten.rx.jdbc.QueryUpdateOnSubscribe.performBeginTransaction(QueryUpdateOnSubscribe.java:115)
    at com.github.davidmoten.rx.jdbc.QueryUpdateOnSubscribe.call(QueryUpdateOnSubscribe.java:78)
```